# Unable to start debug in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio

My "Start debugging" button and element menu are greyed out... but only on one of my projects (an ASP.NET website). I have no idea what I have done to disable it.

I already checked everything in the Property page of both the solution and project. I even compared it to another project, but nothing seems to do the trick... maybe I missed an option ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like your startup projects are all set to "start without debugging", since that would cause the button and element to grey out.

This can be fixed from Solution -> Set StartUp Projects.

Answer (score 3):

Is it a startup project? You can only debug projects that can actually be started.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project and click properties. Then click on Start Options (or something similar) to see the settings. If it's an executable project, you probably want to choose the option that will start the project output.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to start the project, you can usually attach the debugger using Ctrl+Alt+P (Or choose Attach to Process from the Debug-menu) and then choose the process from the list that comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the COM+ Event System service running?